# Unable to submit form with ajax without reloading parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a web application that will create a `div` on the page, use ajax to load a form into that div, and then have the form submitted without the parent page refreshing.  I've read many examples on this site and others of how to do this, yet I'm puzzled why my proof-of-concept test is not working for me.

What successfully happens is that the parent page is creating the new `div` and is loading the form into the div.  However, upon submitting the form, the parent page reloads.  Using "Live HTTP Headers" in Opera, I can see that submitting the form is causing a GET rather than a POST, even though my Javascript is attempting to POST.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?  Any help is very much appreciated.

Here is the code to the parent HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src=\"jquery-1.11.1.min.js\"></script>
  <script src=\"jquery.min.js\"></script>
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var num=1;
    console.log('starting the code');

    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('document is ready');
      $('#form1').submit(function(event) { // catch the form's submit event
        console.log('form is going through submit');
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
          url: 'add_user.php', // the file to call
          type: 'POST', // GET or POST
          data: $('#form1').serialize(), // get the form data
          success: function(data) { // on success..
            $('#assign1').html(data); // update the DIV
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, e) {
            console.log('status');
            console.log('e');
          }
        });
        event.preventDefault(); // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
      });
    });

    function addToBox(divID) {
      console.log('adding new assign to box');
      var myNewDiv = document.createElement(\"div\");
      myNewDivID = 'assign'+num;
      myNewDiv.setAttribute('id', myNewDivID);
      myNewDivID = '#'+myNewDivID;
      var myBox = document.getElementById(divID);
      myBox.appendChild(myNewDiv);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'add_user.php?id=1',
        success: function(data) {
          $(myNewDivID).html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, e) {
          console.log('status');
          console.log('e');
        }
      });
      num+=1;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div id=\"box1\"></div>
  <a href=\"javascript:addToBox('box1')\"><img src=\"/icons/add.png\" alt=\"Create new box\" /></a>
</div>
<div>
  <div id=\"box2\"></div>
  <a href=\"javascript:addToBox('box2')\"><img src=\"/icons/add.png\" alt=\"Create new box\" /></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code to the PHP page (named add_user.php) with the form.

```
<?php
$n=0;
$id=$_GET['id'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {
  echo "got the form!";
} else {
  echo "<form id=\"form{$id}\"><select name=\"quantity\">\n";
  for ($n=1;$n<=5;$n++) {
    echo "<option value=\"answer{$n}\">option {$n}</option>\n";
  }
  echo "</select>\n<input type=\"submit\" /></form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Try calling `event.preventDefault()` before doing anything else. If there is an error, and it doesn't reach the preventDefault call the form will still submit.

Comment: You have to delegate submit event to document level or closest static container...   `$(myNewDivID).on('submit','#form1', function(){...});`  Be aware, there are thousand of similar questions already answered, consider to use the search box on this site next time

Comment: I moved `event.preventDefault()` above the `console.log('form is going through submit');`, but the behavior is the same. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm testing out this `.on` event to see if that will do the trick.

Comment: I replaced `$('#form1').submit(function(event) {` with `$('#assign1').on('submit','#form1', function(){`, but the behavior is the same. Can you reference me to one of those posts so I can understand how to fit this together?

Comment: You're also loading jQuery twice, please remove one.

Comment: @A. Wolff - I replaced `$('#form1').submit(function(event) {` with `$(document).on('submit','#form1', function(){` and it worked! Thanks for the solution!

Comment: #assign1 may not be in the DOM yet either, you have to use something that exists when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by A. Wolff, I replaced `$('#form1').submit(function(event) {` with `$(document).on('submit','#form1', function(event){` and it worked.

Thanks A. Wolff!